# apache not working, shows a “404 page not found” error

Tags: 16.04, apache2

i have been trying to set up apache2 on my ubuntu 16.04 but after successful install i get a 404 page not found error whenever i type localhost in the browser. I have uninstalled and installed apache2 several times but the problem still persists. This is the output of my /var/log/apache2/error.log file..

```
[Tue Jun 26 02:20:52.809104 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1010:tid 139925306578816] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down 
[Tue Jun 26 02:20:58.753357 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1359:tid 139843231913856] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Tue Jun 26 02:20:58.753554 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1359:tid 139843231913856] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Simply repeatedly reinstalling Apache won't help you. Apache requires post-installation configuration. You'l get a better look at the logs with `journalctl /usr/sbin/apache2`

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/apache2` says "No entries"